# html parsing and drawing a visual representation of the dom tree PHP

Tags: php, dom, tree

I am trying to create a web service that takes a url, and returns a graphic representation of it's html tree, or xml. I am trying to parse the html/xml via DOM. Problem is i don't know their structure, and i can't find anywhere a way of parsing a html/xml independent of it's strucuture.

Also a way to draw the tree, i am thinking of using svg for a vectorial representation but for raster representation i dont know what to use. Can anyone help me with some ideas?or some links?

Comment: DOM will suite well for traversal DOM unknown trees

Comment: Yes i know about that, but i need something to help me draw

Comment: To know the structure of a HTML/XML document it's fine to use a parser. An easy one the SimpleXML PHP extension (http://php.net/manual/en/intro.simplexml.php). SVG is a good way to draw, without using any library: just write a .svg file and serve it with the 'image/svg+xml' media type.

Comment: To create a raster image, simply use the GD extension: http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php